# How do I properly change the Title Color of UIButtons on the fly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Problem:

I want to "play back" a series of button presses and play a sound associated with each button played back.

Currently, I am able to "play back" the sounds, but I'd also like to briefly change the Title Color of the UIButtons at the same time the sound is played back.

I've written code that loops through an array that indicates which buttons were pressed.  In this for loop, the sounds play correctly, but none of the button titles change color until after the method with the loop exits.

i.e. during the loop the sound plays, but the title text doesn't change color until after the loop totally exits and the code steps out of the method.  I've determined this by setting a breakpoint and watching the behavior.

What I see on the screen is - I press the button to start the sequence, the sounds play, and then after the sounds quit playing, the buttons change their title color all at once.

How can I get it so that each button only changes its title color when the sound play?

I hope that makes some sort of sense, and thank you if you spent the time to read all this. :)

Comment: You said that you are looping through buttons for finding which button is pressed... but why you use loops?? Instead you can fetch id and then use tag property... and based on that you can firstly change the Title color of button and then you start the PlayBack.... sorry If i am wrong somewhere but please put the portion of the code that creates problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loop through all your sounds and animations , the loop executes too quickly and you have no control over the timing of the animations.

Instead, you could use a `NSTimer` and do each sound and animation discreetly each time the timer fires.

Comment: I like that idea Mundi!  And since you said you've done something similar to what I'm trying to do and it worked for you, then I should be able to get it to work!  :)  It never occurred to me to use a timer.

Comment: Hey Mundi, it's almost working now!  Now the title text is changing color as the sound is played.  AWESOME.  Now, though, I want to title text to change back to the previous color after the sound plays.  Do I need to use another timer for that?

Comment: @Terry - Yes that is a the way I do it. When you change the color you can send a non-repeating timer under way to change it back. -- Please consider accepting the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean your button won't change color at the correct time even though you have the code in the right place correct? That's because the drawing isn't updated right away, so you need something like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeColor) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

- (void)changeColor
{
    [UIButton setTitleColor:YOUR_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

That will halt the program until the color is updated and redrawn allowing it to show correctly.

Comment: Cool!  I figured it was something like that.  Trying it now.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I get the same behavior as I described.  I have been using a NSThread sleepForTimeInterval to make sure one sound finishes before the other, so I figured your method would help that work too.  When I get rid of the sleep, the sounds play on top of each other, and then the button title changes color.

Comment: Just verified with breakpoints that the colors don't change until after the method with the loop exits.  Also verified that the selector is being called properly.  It just doesn't seem like we're waiting.  Also made sure to set the waitUntilDone arg to YES.

Comment: try adding [Button setNeedsDisplay] as well.

Comment: Just tried that Xen.  Still no dice.  Gonna try Mundi's suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might try to make sue the sounds play in a background thread while the UI updates continue in the main thread.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playSound:) withObject:sound];
```

In `playSound`, don't forget to establish a new autorelease pool, so you don't leak memory.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, I'll try that.  Maybe a combination of your answer and Xen's will get me what I'm looking for...

Comment: Mundi, that didn't seem to change the behavior at all.  Still having the same problem as described above...

Comment: I just programmed something like this yesterday, i.e. piano keys that play by themselves, with both visual and acoustic feedback. However, I am not using any threading at all. When the timer fires, I change the image of my key buttons, and then play the sound with AVAudioPlayer. So perhaps you should time the playing and button animations with a `NSTimer` & a counter rather than going through a loop.

Comment: How are you setting the image back to the previous, unplayed state?  Does that require another timer?